# BigQuery error "Query returned no results"

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, cryptography, ethereum

```sql
SELECT address, eth_balance FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.balances`
    WHERE address = '0x5245A7C4Cac42f20FC352491c4b7127c5bf30A44';
```

Or changing the query to this:

```sql
SELECT address, eth_balance FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.balances`
    WHERE address LIKE '0x5245A7C4Cac42f20FC352491c4b7127c5bf30A44';
```

And other address like this do not pull up the address or amount:

Error message: `This query returned no results.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just lower it :-)
Looks like you accidentally changed your address to UPPERCASE or BQ stored it in LOWER case ... anyhow if you lowercase the addresses as shown below you'll start seeing balances.

```
#standardSQL 
SELECT address, eth_balance 
FROM bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.balances 
where address = lower('0x5245A7C4Cac42f20FC352491c4b7127c5bf30A44') ;
```

Returns:

```
address                                     eth_balance
0x5245a7c4cac42f20fc352491c4b7127c5bf30a44  23743356716445772
```

Comment: A valiant effort to answer what I considered to be an unanswerable question.

Comment: Just my 3rd answer on SO ... really appreciate the positive feedback. :-)

Comment: Great answer, thanks for the quick accurate response.